# What is NSHeartBeatThread?

Tags: objective-c

I was recently debugging my application in Instruments and one of the threads was "NSHeartBeat" (or something very similar).  None of my methods have the word "heart" or "beat" in them, so I'm assuming it's a system function.  What does it do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It animates progress indicators and default buttons, maybe other things, I've never seen full list (it is not documented). Check the discussion at http://cocoadev.com/wiki/NSUIHeartBeat